# Separable Differential Equation Help

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I just can't seem to get this one. I know the process at least what we learned is to:

Get all the y's on one side and the x's on another
Integrate each side
Solve for some $C$ given a $x$ and $y$ value.
I just want to know how to set up the integration.

$$\frac{dy}{dx} - x * e^y = 2 * e^y$$

Comment: Can you get all the $y$'s on one side and the non-$y$'s on the other??

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

After separation (divide by $e^y$), you have:

$$\int e^{-y} dy = \int (x+2) dx$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: You can rewrite

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} - xe^y = 2e^y
$$

as

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = (2+x) e^y
$$

and then separate variables like you normally would.

Comment: i guess i got confused when I got dy / e^y. does this become e^-y dy?

Comment: Yes. Look at Amzoti's comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is question which can be solved using variable separation,

$\frac {dy}{dx}=e^y(x+2)$

Now dividing both sides by $e^y$ and multiplying by dx and integrating

$\int\frac{dy}{e^y}=\int e^{-y}\space. dy=\int (x + 2).dx$

$-e^{-y}=\frac{x^2}{2}+2x +c$

which is the answer.